# libxml2 xmlChar* cast to char*

Tags: c++, casting, libxml2

How would you convert / cast an xmlChar* to char* from the libxml2 library? Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

If you take a look at the examples, for instance io2.c, you'll notice that they just blithely cast it to a char *:

```
printf("%s", (char *) xmlbuff);
```

Answer (score 6):

[Looks like](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlstring.html) it's just unsigned char.  So it should be safe to cast as long as you're not doing arithmetic on it.

*But*, you probably don't need to as that page has the key string functionality implemented in terms of the type.

Comment: *For now*, it's unsigned char - but why make a simple alias for char if they don't expect the typedef to change in the future?